# How to find out the latest available microcode version for an AMD CPU?

Tags: cpu, amd-ryzen

While for Intel there is information like [microcode-update-guidance.pdf](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/corporate-information/SA00233-microcode-update-guidance.pdf) and [releasenote](https://github.com/intel/Intel-Linux-Processor-Microcode-Data-Files/blob/master/releasenote), I could not find similar information about AMD CPU microcode updates.

Is it available anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing I could find is this community run microcode repository for Intel, VIA and AMD processors: https://github.com/platomav/CPUMicrocodes/

The list of AMD microcodes (with version numbers) is here:
https://github.com/platomav/CPUMicrocodes/tree/master/AMD

Explanation of the filenames is in the first link. In short, it contains:

- CPUID
- Revision (Microcode update revision counter)
- Date (Date of its public release)
- Checksum